# Audit/Log all incoming web requests to @RequestMapping annotated methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Source

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping

I have Controller classes annotated with @Controller, they have methods annotated with @RequestMapping. **My task is to audit all the web requests received by the Controller classes to @RequestMapping methods**, I am using datatables on UI to send and receive response from controllers. the Audit framework is already in place.

The project is configured in Java Config.

I am not sure how to proceed on getting this done.

```
// Configure Interceptor

public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(new MyInterceptor());
}

public @Bean
RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
    RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping = new RequestMappingHandlerMapping();
    handlerMapping.setAlwaysUseFullPath(true);
    handlerMapping.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
    return handlerMapping;
  }
}

//Add Handler
@Component
public class MyInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
@Inject RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping;
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
        throws Exception {
// do stuff - ( Does my Audit Code go here? eg: Logger.info("xyz request"))
return true;
 }
}
```

I was thinking something like this would work.

Any Suggestions on this, and
if its easier Using Listener or some other Interceptor, it would be helpful

Comment: @Betlista Can you point me to an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using interceptors you have full access to the [HandlerMethod](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/HandlerMethod.html) which provides convenient access to method parameters, the method return value, method annotations, etc.

The following example intercepts and logs mapped requests.

```
class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

   @Override
   public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
      registry.addInterceptor(new HandlerInterceptorAdapter() {
         Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebMvcConfig.class);

         @Override
         public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
            if (handler instanceof HandlerMethod) {
               HandlerMethod handlerMethod = (HandlerMethod) handler;
               Method method = handlerMethod.getMethod();
               logger.info("{} - {} - method '{}' on controller '{}'",
                     request.getMethod(), request.getRequestURI(), method.getName(),
                     handlerMethod.getBean().getClass()
               );
            }
            return true;
         }
      });
   }
}
```

It returns true to continue with the execution chain (and forward the request to other interceptors or the controller-method itself).

An example log-output looks like:

`GET - /greeting - method 'greeting' on controller 'class hello.GreetingController'`

Comment: That worked great.  Can i further filter which mapped request to Log? using wildcards or any other way? or by avoiding some controller class?

Comment: Look at the https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/InterceptorRegistration.html javadoc. You can add path-patterns to which the registered interceptor should apply to. If that is not enough you could implement a custom include/exclude filter that fits your needs in your customized `HandlerInterceptor` implementation. Since you have access to the `HandlerMethod` you have access to pretty much everything - even introducing your own Method- or Class-level annotations to mark a method/controller is possible.